# IKEv2 Site to Site from Cisco ASA 5506 to Azure "RouteBased" VPN

Tags: cisco-asa, vpn, ike

I am having a little bit of a problem setting up a IKEv2 site to site to Azure cloud. I am using the IPSec permaeters from [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-about-vpn-devices) document.

Phase1 is established, but I cant figure out Phase2, here is the crypto config:

#### Config

```
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES-SHA esp-aes esp-sha-hmac
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set azure-ipsec-proposal-set esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac
crypto ipsec ikev2 ipsec-proposal azure-ikev2-ipsec-proposal-set
 protocol esp encryption aes-gcm-256
 protocol esp integrity sha-1
crypto ipsec security-association lifetime seconds 3600
crypto ipsec security-association lifetime kilobytes 102400000
crypto ipsec security-association pmtu-aging infinite
crypto map outside_map 10 match address vpn-traffic-ikev2
crypto map outside_map 10 set peer 1.1.1.1
crypto map outside_map 10 set ikev2 ipsec-proposal azure-ikev2-ipsec-proposal-set
crypto map outside_map interface outside
crypto ca trustpool policy
crypto ikev2 policy 5
 encryption aes-256 3des
 integrity sha256 sha
 group 2
 prf sha
 lifetime seconds 10800
crypto ikev2 enable outside
crypto ikev2 enable Comcast
```

#### Debug

Its lengthy so I will just paste where the problem is:

```
IKEv2-PROTO-2: (34): Processing IKE_AUTH message
IKEv2-PROTO-1: (34): Failed to find a matching policy
IKEv2-PROTO-1: (34): Received Policies:
ESP: Proposal 1:  AES-GCM-256 Don't use ESN

ESP: Proposal 2:  AES-CBC-256 SHA96 Don't use ESN

ESP: Proposal 3:  AES-CBC-256 SHA256 Don't use ESN

ESP: Proposal 4:  AES-CBC-128 SHA96 Don't use ESN

ESP: Proposal 5:  3DES SHA96 Don't use ESN

ESP: Proposal 6:  3DES SHA256 Don't use ESN

ESP: Proposal 7:  DES SHA96 Don't use ESN

ESP: Proposal 8:  AES-CBC-256 SHA96 Don't use ESN

ESP: Proposal 9:  AES-CBC-256 SHA96 Don't use ESN

ESP: Proposal 10:  AES-CBC-256 SHA96 Don't use ESN

ESP: Proposal 11:  AES-CBC-128 SHA96 Don't use ESN

ESP: Proposal 12:  AES-CBC-128 SHA96 Don't use ESN

ESP: Proposal 13:  AES-CBC-128 SHA96 Don't use ESN

ESP: Proposal 14:  3DES SHA96 Don't use ESN

ESP: Proposal 15:  3DES SHA96 Don't use ESN

ESP: Proposal 16:  3DES SHA256 Don't use ESN

ESP: Proposal 17:  AES-CBC-256 SHA256 Don't use ESN

ESP: Proposal 18:  AES-CBC-256 SHA256 Don't use ESN

ESP: Proposal 19:  AES-CBC-256 SHA256 Don't use ESN

ESP: Proposal 20:  AES-CBC-256 SHA96 Don't use ESN

ESP: Proposal 21:  AES-CBC-256 SHA256 Don't use ESN

ESP: Proposal 22:  AES-CBC-128 SHA256 Don't use ESN

ESP: Proposal 23:  AES-CBC-128 SHA256 Don't use ESN

ESP: Proposal 24:  AES-CBC-128 SHA256 Don't use ESN

ESP: Proposal 25:  AES-CBC-128 SHA256 Don't use ESN

ESP: Proposal 26:  3DES SHA96 Don't use ESN

IKEv2-PROTO-1: (34): Failed to find a matching policy
IKEv2-PROTO-1: (34): Expected Policies:
IKEv2-PROTO-5: (34): Failed to verify the proposed policies
IKEv2-PROTO-1: (34): Failed to find a matching policy
```

So from the debug its obvious that I have the policies messed up during the Phase2 negotiation process, but according to debug Proposal 1 should be AES-GCM-256, which is what I have configured.

#### Phase1 Tunnel

```
IKEv2 SAs:
Session-id:44, Status:UP-IDLE, IKE count:1, CHILD count:0

Tunnel-id     Local                Remote     Status         Role
980175485     2.2.2.2/500     1.1.1.1/500      READY    RESPONDER
      Encr: AES-CBC, keysize: 256, Hash: SHA96, DH Grp:2, Auth sign: PSK, Auth verify: PSK
      Life/Active Time: 10800/26 sec
```

Comment: Azure Cloud "Route Based" VPNs do not support Cisco ASA's, I switched the tunnel type to "Policy Based" on the Azure side, modified the config on the ASA to use IKEv1 and the tunnel popped up immediately.

Document: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-about-vpn-devices

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Cloud "Route Based" VPNs do not support Cisco ASA's, I switched the tunnel type to "Policy Based" on the Azure side, modified the config on the ASA to use IKEv1 and the tunnel popped up immediately.

Answer (score 3):

Azure Route-Based VPNs actually do support Cisco ASAs, but you have to configure Policy Based Traffic Selectors on the Azure Gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following line and it will work.

```
crypto map outside_map 10 set pfs group24
```

I believe the VPN configuration for the ASA was created using the download configuration script of Azure. It does not add the below line in the configuration hence the issue.

https://docs.microsoft.com/sl-si/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-3rdparty-device-config-cisco-asa

Hope that helps.

Thanks,
Abs